# Rails specify controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a folder views/home that contains the initial screen for a Rails app.

For some users, the home.index.html.erb displays a partial containing a list of workorkorders.

In other words I'm fetching a list of workorder and a list of worequests from the home/index.html.erb - therefore, I've added code to read the @workorders and @worequests into the home controller.

This is the code that fetches the workorders:

```
<% @workorders.notcompl.each do |workorder| %>
```

The home controller contains this code to fetch the workorders:

```
def index
  @workorders = Workorder.all
```

I'd like to have _agentopenrequests.html.erb fetch all of the worequests.
So, I added the following to fetch the wore quests:

```
def index2
  @worequests = Worequest.all
```

But, in the partial thats executed from home/index.html.erb file, how do get the following line to use `index2` instead of `index`?

```
  <% @worequests.notcompl.each do |worequest| %>
```

Should I put both @worequests and @workorders into `index`?

---

### UPDATE1

I tried changing the home controller to this:

```
 def index
   @workorders = Workorder.all

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }
   end

   @worequests = Worequest.all

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
   end
 end
```

But, I get

```
DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action.
```

UPDATE2

Would it make more sense to have the partial in the worequests folder instead of home - so, the worequests controller gets used?

Comment: sorry but for me its not really clear what you are asking..

Comment: For UPDATE2, controllers aren't invoked when rendering partials. You can place partials in any view folder. They will render as long as you call the correct path from a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all `index2` does is pull a collection of worequests, you can copy/move it to the `index` action.

Comment: zeantsoi's answer is a visualization of mine. Assign two instance variables (one for `Workorder.all` and one for `Worequest.all`), then call one `respond_to` block. Instance methods defined in this action will be available to all layouts and partials rendered from it.

Comment: In other words, you don't have to re-render the view each time you assign a new instance variable. Assign as many as you like, then render once. **ALL** instance variables will pass through to the view upon rendering.